# How to run infinite-loop python script that includes external .py script that's non-blocking but yet needs a response

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, infinite-loop, python-multithreading, external-script

I have two .py scripts. One is a infinite-loop(infinite.py) and the other is a test order on a website(order.py).

I need to execute order.py externally for x. I need this to be non blocking so that my infinite loop can keep checking the other items to see if I need to run order.py for the next "x" that gets popped out from list. The problem is that order.py takes 2 minutes to complete and I need a return of some kind to perform some logic that states if the order was successful, to add x back to list. I do not want "x" to be back in list yet or else it will try to perform another order.py on the same item from list.

I have tried to use subprocess.Popen and call but I can't seem to get them to work. I can either get it to run externally and be non-blocking but I won't be able to get my response from order.py or I get order.py to run but the infinite.py is waiting for order.py to finish before continuing with loop. I have also tried threading as well

```py
Here is the structure of my code.

list = ["item1", "item2", "item3", "item4"]


while True:
    x = list.pop(0)

    #Performs a simple check 1
    if check is True:

        #Performs check 2
        if check2 is True:


            # This is the section I need help with.
            # I need to execute order.py and wait for a response while this 
            # infinite loop keeps going

            if order.py is successful:
                list.append(x)
            else:
                print("Problem with order.py")
                list.append(x)
        else:
            list.append(x)
            time.sleep(30)
            pass
    else:
        list.append(x)
        time.sleep(30)
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

So after asking a few people I realized what I am trying to do will never work. An example that explained to me was imagine a hand of poker where the current hand is no finished so you do not know the results of your earning before placing a new bet with your current chips. I am closing this post.